# Remapping Caps Lock for every session

Tags: ubuntu, x11, login, keyboard-layout

I use the following command to remap the Caps Lock key to Esc:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:escape
```

Unfortunately, I have to type the command every time I create a new session. I tried putting it in my .bashrc but it did not work. I guess the keyboard settings must be getting overwritten somehow after the .bashrc has run.

How can make the key binding automatically occur?

Comment: Typically, you would put it in your X initialisation file (`~/.xinitrc`), but if you are using a display manager, that may not get read. How do you start X?

Comment: @jasonwryan I don't know it is ubuntu. I just start ubuntu then press Ctrl-Shift-T

Comment: Doesn't Ubuntu have some sort of keyboard utility: you probably need to define it there. This should probably be migrated to AU...

Comment: did you try adding the command to startup applications?

Answer (score 2):

If your ubuntu is not too old (? probably at least 15.04), you should have a command `locatectl` which on its own will list some current settings eg:

```
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: us
   X11 Layout: us
    X11 Model: pc105
```

Note the values for layout, model, variant, and options if any and provide them to `sudo localectl` in that order, with your new option added with a comma to any existing options. If the model is missing it is probably pc105 (see also `setxkbmap -print`). Eg

```
sudo localectl set-x11-keymap us pc105 '' caps:escape
```

You only need to use the command once, as it changes global files and is preserved across reboots. `localectl` is part of systemd. See `man localectl`.

Comment: this does not persist through the computer sleeping; when it comes back from sleep the escape key is no longer changed even it says it is changed in localectl

Comment: that seems unusual. there really must be something which has another config file it is using to restore a different setting. Edit your question with which version of Ubuntu you are using, in case that helps someone find an answer.